# Content isn't updated on Tab click

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Using the iPad, selecting one of the options shown in the pictures below doesn't change the page's content.

> [image]

---

> [image]

It seems like it is changing only after page refresh.

Comment: Michael, I also noticed one thing, apart from page refresh, you can tap  (after selection is made)  on "Show/Hide excerpts" tab and the content gets refreshed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original intent of the dropdown was selecting your home tab (the one you see when clicking the logo). But since this seems to confuse some people we'll be trying to bounce you to that tab after it's been selected there as well. Rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.7.24.3607` on MSE/MSO, `2015.7.24.2749` on sites).